# Finding div(s) inside of a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

My **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2LZW/)** does not work like it does on my machine locally. I can actually drag the elements. Nevertheless, it can work as a visual for what I am trying to acheive.

I can already drag and drop the `units` to the `divs` below the *pool* but I want to be able to save their location. To be more specific: I want to send an ajax request back to a php file with the location of the `units`, the `container` it was dragged into so I can save it my `categories` table I have in a database so when the page is loaded back it will load the `units` in their respected `categories` which I am referring to as `containers`.

I just do not know how to get the data I want. Here is a rough pseudo code of what I am attempting

---

```
var array_for_container1[]; //to hold the units in the first container
var array_for_container2[]; //to do the same
//etc
//loop through each container and get the units inside
//place each unit into the array it needs to be in
//send to php with ajax request
```

---

Now I am creating the `containers` dynamically so I will have to somehow have an array to hold the `units` for each of them. Basically I'll have to find out how many `containers` there are so I can get a number of arrays to create and the number of `containers` to loop through. If anyone has suggestions on how to do that I would greatly appreciate it, however, that isn't the goal of this post. My goal in this post is to know what `units` are in which `containers`

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include jQuery UI which is needed for `draggable`

Comment: The order of your includes (external resources) are wrong, I have changed them in your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2LZW/3/). First jquery, then jquery-ui...

Answer (score 0):

Well, with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DwYe8/1/), I've simplified your code just down to the html.

Then I've written a little script that goes through all of the labels, counts them and puts their html contents into an array.

The number of labels and the array are then printed out into two test divs.

Here is the js:

```
var counter = 0;
var contentarray = new Array();
$('label').each(function(index){
    contentarray[counter] = $(this).html();
    counter = counter +1;
});

$('.output1').html(counter);
$('.output2').html(contentarray);
```

Seems to work.